# Creating a New Record in Join Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called Notifications, which basically acts as a join table between Requests and Accommodations.

In my "create" method in my Requests controller, I have:

```
   # find associated accommodations, currently matching: location
    @accommodations = Accommodation.where('location' => :location)
    @accommodations.each do |accommodation|
      @notification = @request.notification.build('accommodation_id' => accommodation.id ).save
    end
```

Which doesn't seem to be creating a new Notification record. What am I doing wrong here?

**models/accommodation.rb**

```
class Accommodation < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title, :description, :thing, :location, :spaces, :price, :photo
  attr_accessible :photo_attributes, :title, :description, :thing, :location, :spaces, :price
  has_one :photo
  has_many :notifications
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**models/notification.rb**

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :accommodation_id, :request_id
  has_one :request
end
```

**models/request.rb**

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname, :email, :phone, :datestart, :dateend, :adults, :children, :location, :status
  validates_presence_of :firstname, :lastname, :email, :phone, :datestart, :dateend, :children, :adults, :location
  has_many :notifications
end
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to join? You just posted code...

Comment: Sorry-- maybe my question wasn't exactly obvious. It was smushed between the first and second code blocks! It's "Which doesn't seem to be creating a new Notification record. What am I doing wrong here?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't define @request or :location in your controller. Assuming it's a Request object:

```
@notifications = Array.new

@accommodations = Accommodation.where('location' => :location)
Accommodation.find_each(:conditions => { 'location' => :location }) do |a|
  notification = @request.notifications.create('accommodation_id' => a.id)
  @notifications << notifications
end
```

Just like @AnomalousThought said:

> There's a lot to be said about the
>   example provided, I think the
>   implementation is entirely poor. But
>   that's not relative to the question of
>   why the notification record isn't saving.

Comment: What would be a better implementation? This works (thanks!)-- all I'm trying to do is create a new Notification record for each Accommodation record that matches the conditions (currently just :location-- which should actually be @request.location... Oops). If there's a better way to do this, please let me know! I'm very open to learning here.

Comment: Could you please describe your actual problem a little more. I'm not sure exactly what a notification, accommodation, and request are... Could you explain what exactly their relationship is and how you plan to use them? I can give you a better response that way...

Comment: Thanks Seth. I'm building an app for bed and breakfast businesses. Accommodations are just that-- accommodation listings. Since accommodations may or may not be available and I have no way of knowing since I don't run them, I accept a Request first from a visitor, and then create a Notification for each accommodation. A notification sends an e-mail off to the accommodation owner (a User), who then can accept or reject it. The visitor then gets e-mails for each acceptance, who can choose the one they like. This is why I have a "join" table-- a single Request can have multiple Notifications.

Comment: hmm... okay and an accommodation is a room? is a request like a search? I'm pretty versed in created travel sites, but ive never dealt with B&bs

Comment: Basically, yeah. But the request gets stored in the db, since it needs to be referenced later (ie; the visitor ends up renting one of the accommodations... the accommodation owner needs the visitor's contact info)

Comment: on a side note, i dont recommend using email. use an internal site-notification system and send a notice to the user that they have messages, not the actual messages, if that makes sense. email is insecure

Comment: Good call Seth. I'm actually doing this already, hence the idea of "notifications". It only sends them an e-mail if a visitor selects their accommodation and "checks out" (makes a deposit).

Answer (score 1):

`@request.notification.build` should be `@request.notification`**s**`.build` since a request has_many notifications.

Also, you're setting `@notification` to become the value of what the .save returns which will only be `true` or `false`. You might want to use `create` if you want `@notification` to point to the actual object. Additionally, you probably already know that it's going to keep overwriting the `@notification` variable on every iteration, which you may or may not want.

There's a lot to be said about the example provided, I think the implementation is entirely poor. But that's not relative to the question of why the notification record isn't saving.

Comment: Even though I posted an answer, I'm up-voting yours and appending your last paragraph to mine because I completely agree - There's a lot to be said about the example provided, I think the implementation is entirely poor. But that's not relative to the question of why the notification record isn't saving.